# Hive array specifying multiple delimiter in collection

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have dataset contains two arrays, both arrays separated by different delimiter..
Ex: 14-20-50-60 is 1st array seperated by -
12#2#333#4 is 2nd array seperated by #..

While creating table how do we specify delimiter in
Collection items terminated by '' ?

**input** 
14-20-50-60,12#2#333#4

```
create table test(first array<string>, second array<string>)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
collection items terminated by '-' (How to specify two delimiters in the collection)
```

Comment: Can you give us the code you have tried so far so that we can help enhance it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use multiple delimiters for the collection items. You can achieve what you are trying to do as below though. I have used the SPLIT function to create the array using different delimiters.

Data

```
14-20-50-60,12#2#333#4
```

SQL - CREATE TABLE

```
create external table test1(first string, second string)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
LOCATION  '/user/cloudera/ramesh/test1';
```

SQL - SELECT

```
WITH v_test_array AS
(SELECT split(first, "-") AS first_array,  
        split(second, "#") AS second_array  
   FROM test1)
SELECT first_array[0], second_array[0]
  FROM v_test_array;
```

OUTPUT

```
14  12
```

Hope this helps.